# FreeRADIUS error Refusing to start due to insecure configuration

Tags: freeradius, radius

Fri Feb 28 13:12:34 2020 : Error: /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/files[9]: Invalid configuration for module "files"
Fri Feb 28 13:12:39 2020 : Info: Debugger not attached
Fri Feb 28 13:12:39 2020 : Error: Configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-config/files/authorize is globally writable.  Refusing to start due to insecure configuration.

Answer (score 2):

The FreeRADIUS configuration files shouldn't be globally writeable, as it will allow any user on the system to change the config. Because this is a security issue, FreeRADIUS refuses to start until the file permissions are set correctly.

You can fix this by removing the public write access from the authorize file, e.g. with

```
chmod o-w /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-config/files/authorize
```

(In the vast majority of situations the config shouldn't be publicly readable, either.)